# How to add extension Allow CORS in Android Tab Chrome browser

Tags: applications, security, chrome-for-android, samsung-galaxy-s-6

I need to open a website in mobile chrome browser. Its not opening there is CORS issue. I fixed that issue in Laptop added a extension Allow CORS in Chrome browser. When I tried in mobile there is no option to add extension.

How can I fix this issue in Samsung Tab is there any workaround ?

Comment: Chrome for Android doesn't support extensions. You have to use other browsers.

Comment: @AndrewT. - Kiwi Browser solved my issue.